# my 'if' function won't work with strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's a simple question:

```
lacount=0
ptcount=0
for line in list1:
    print(str(line))
    if 'LA'==str(line):
        lacount+=1

    if 'PT'==str(line):
        print('pt works')
        ptcount+=1
```

I'm trying to count how many `'PT'` and `'LA'` there are in a list but it seems like the `if` statements are not working, as my value still remains as a zero. Can someone help please?

The list I print out via the coding above comes out as:

```
PMID
TI  
DP  
AU  
AU  
AU  
JT  
LA  
PT  


PMID
TI  
DP  
AU  
JT  
LA  
PT  


PMID
TI  
LID 
DP  
JT  
AU  
AU  
LA  
PT

PT = 0
LA = 0
```

Comment: Where is the list coming from? Reading a file? Are you `rstrip`-ing the trailing newlines on each line?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add an example `list1` for which your code fails. Tag me when you're done.

Comment: 'list1' is coming from a imported file. And my program never failed, it just never really counted the numbers i needed. thats all. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `strip()` will remove any whitespaces that might've been in the string:

```
lacount=0
ptcount=0
for line in list1:
        print(str(line))
        if 'LA'==str(line).strip():
                lacount+=1

        if 'PT'==str(line).strip():
                print('pt works')
                ptcount+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your reference text that feeds into this function but try this:

```py
lacount, ptcount = 0, 0
for line in list1:
        print(str(line))
        if 'LA' in str(line):
                lacount+=1

        if 'PT' in str(line):
                print('pt works')
                ptcount+=1
```

If you have multiple occurrences in a line:

```py
lacount=0
ptcount=0
for line in list1:
        laccount += str(line).count('LA')
        ptcount += str(line).count('PT')
```

Comment: This won't work if the strings are more than 2 characters long.

Comment: Really? - I tested this `print('bananas'.count('an'))` and got a value of 2 - is that what you are talking about?

Comment: For example, there is `PTG` in the list.

Comment: Interesting - hmm - BTW I see you on SO all the time - Your YouTube videos are great, keep it up!